# How to fix numpy dependencies path on a python 3.7.3 script on Linux frozen with cx_Freeze 6.0b1?

Tags: linux, python-3.x, numpy, cx-freeze

I am using Debian 9, python 3.7.3 and cx_Freeze 6.0b1. I spent some time installing cx_Freeze on Windows 7 and Debian, I managed to compile the script on both platforms.

When I share it, the Windows version runs, but the Linux version raises an error about missing dependencies. The app is still looking for the files in the absolute path, and I don't understand why.

When I run cx_Freeze, the `.so` file are copied to the output directory.

---

My compiled program:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f=open('hello.txt','w')
f.write('Hello World')
f.close()

y=lambda x:np.sqrt(x)
x=range(10)
plt.plot(x,y(x))
plt.show()
```

---

My `setup.py` program:

```py
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
exclude = []
executables = [
Executable('hello.py', base=None, targetName='Hello')]
includes=["encodings"]

include_files=[]
includes=[]
packages=["numpy","matplotlib"]

setup(
name = "Hello",
version = "1 ",
description = "Hello World",
options = {'build_exe':{"packages":packages, "include_files":include_files,'excludes':exclude,'includes':includes}},
executables = executables
)
```

---

Error while trying to execute the app on a second computer:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ansart/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cx_Freeze/initscripts/__startup__.py", line 14, in run
  File "/home/ansart/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cx_Freeze/initscripts/Console.py", line 26, in run
  File "hello.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ansart/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
  File "/home/ansart/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/_distributor_init.py", line 34, in <module>
ImportError: libmkl_rt.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

---

Error while trying to execute the app on a third computer:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/ansart/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cx_Freeze/initscripts/__startup__.py", line 14, in run
 File "/home/ansart/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cx_Freeze/initscripts/Console.py", line 26, in run
 File "hello.py", line 1, in <module>
 File "/home/ansart/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
 File "/home/ansart/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/_distributor_init.py", line 33, in <module>
 File "/home/ansart/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/_distributor_init.py", line 18, in __enter__
 File "/home/ansart/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
ImportError: libffi.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

---

List of files in the directory:

```
total 97649
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vansart 197121  3464464 juin  11 14:55 Hello
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vansart 197121       11 juin  11 17:28 hello.txt
drwxrwxrwx 1 vansart 197121        0 juin  12 08:33 imageformats/
drwxrwxrwx 1 vansart 197121        0 juin  12 08:33 lib/
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vansart 197121   840264 janv. 17 21:31 libblosc.so.1
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vansart 197121  3452736 juin   7 16:48 libcrypto.so.1.1
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vansart 197121   409720 juin   7 16:48 libdbus-1.so.3
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vansart 197121   225424 août  27  2018 libexpat.so.1
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vansart 197121    99936 janv. 19 19:34 libexslt.so.0
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vansart 197121    40864 nov.   8  2017 libffi.so.6
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vansart 197121   324384 juin   7 16:48 libfontconfig.so.1
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vansart 197121   778224 août  24  2018 libfreetype.so.6
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vansart 197121   819744 août  17  2018 libgcc_s.so.1
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vansart 197121  5925928 août  18  2018 libgfortran.so.4
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vansart 197121  1321984 juin   7 16:48 libglib-2.0.so.0
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vansart 197121    16200 août  28  2018 libgthread-2.0.so.0
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vansart 197121  4085608 juin   7 16:48 libhdf5.so.103
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vansart 197121 26215496 nov.  16  2017 libicudata.so.58
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vansart 197121  3227376 nov.  16  2017 libicui18n.so.58
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vansart 197121  2041320 nov.  16  2017 libicuuc.so.58
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vansart 197121   263880 nov.   9  2017 libjpeg.so.9
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vansart 197121   173408 mai   16  2018 liblzma.so.5
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vansart 197121  6628244 mars  14 21:00 libmkl_rt.so
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vansart 197121   272240 nov.  28  2018 libncursesw.so.6
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vansart 197121   296792 mars  12 20:41 libpcre.so.1
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vansart 197121   252920 janv. 11 20:20 libpng16.so.16
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vansart 197121  4270856 juin   7 16:48 libQt5Core.so.5
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vansart 197121   386744 déc.  12 09:48 libQt5DBus.so.5
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vansart 197121   519048 déc.  12 09:48 libQt5EglFSDeviceIntegration.so.5
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vansart 197121  3954056 déc.  12 09:48 libQt5Gui.so.5
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vansart 197121  1183672 déc.  12 09:48 libQt5Network.so.5
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vansart 197121   305760 déc.  12 09:48 libQt5Svg.so.5
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vansart 197121  5440440 déc.  12 09:48 libQt5Widgets.so.5
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vansart 197121    14640 déc.  12 09:48 libQt5X11Extras.so.5
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vansart 197121   971848 déc.  12 09:48 libQt5XcbQpa.so.5
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vansart 197121   864776 août  17  2018 libquadmath.so.0
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vansart 197121   372072 août  28  2018 libreadline.so.7
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vansart 197121    42336 nov.  27  2017 libsnappy.so.1
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vansart 197121   395472 mars  28  2018 libsodium.so.23
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vansart 197121  1233456 mars  12 20:13 libsqlite3.so.0
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vansart 197121   695960 mars   7 16:42 libssl.so.1.1
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vansart 197121  9536208 août  17  2018 libstdc++.so.6
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vansart 197121  1970968 juin   7 16:48 libtcl8.6.so
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vansart 197121   550704 janv. 28 21:29 libtiff.so.5
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vansart 197121   266064 juin   7 16:48 libtinfow.so.6
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vansart 197121  1580952 août  28  2018 libtk8.6.so
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vansart 197121    18472 janv. 11  2018 libuuid.so.1
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vansart 197121   215392 avr.  13  2018 libxcb.so.1
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vansart 197121    24552 avr.  13  2018 libxcb-dri2.so.0
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vansart 197121    23736 avr.  13  2018 libxcb-dri3.so.0
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vansart 197121   154312 avr.  13  2018 libxcb-glx.so.0
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vansart 197121    13784 avr.  13  2018 libxcb-present.so.0
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vansart 197121    34912 avr.  13  2018 libxcb-sync.so.1
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vansart 197121    45936 avr.  13  2018 libxcb-xfixes.so.0
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vansart 197121  1714896 janv. 19 16:11 libxml2.so.2
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vansart 197121   297000 juin   7 16:48 libxslt.so.1
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vansart 197121   133384 nov.  21  2018 libz.so.1
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vansart 197121   731928 févr.  1 13:16 libzmq.so.5
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vansart 197121   696896 nov.   6  2018 libzstd.so.1.3.7
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vansart 197121        0 juin  12 11:31 list.txt
drwxrwxrwx 1 vansart 197121        0 juin  12 08:33 mpl-data/
drwxrwxrwx 1 vansart 197121        0 juin  12 08:33 platforms/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to manually copy all the `lib*.so.*` files into the `lib` subdirectory of the frozen application before sharing. Does this solve your problem? If yes, you could automatize this step using `shutil.copy2` at the end of your `setup.py` script for example.

Regarding your comment:

> The app is still looking for the files in the absolute path, and I don't understand why

I guess you refer to the paths appearing in the tracebacks. These are filenames attached to code objects which presumably do not get actualized when the frozen application is moved. You can let cx_Freeze replace these absolute paths through relative ones by adding an entry

```
'replace_paths': [("*", "")]
```

to the `build_exe` option dictionary in the `setup.py` script. See [issue #247](https://github.com/anthony-tuininga/cx_Freeze/issues/247) on the cx_Freeze repository and the links therein.

Comment: It doesn't work. I copy every  `.so` file to the root and lib folder, and it raises the same error

Comment: @ansarto Which version of numpy are you using?

Comment: it is numpy 1.16.2.
I try with the 1.16.3, like my windows installation. It works on some computers, but raise other errors
I still have the `libffi.so.6` file from numpy missing, and sometime some matplotlib files.