# How to "hide" some .py files into .exe with cx_Freeze?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, cx-freeze, decompiling

#### Env:

Windows 10
python 3.6.6
cx-Freeze 5.0.2

#### [Git hub example](https://github.com/Yuriy-Leonov/installer-with-cx_Freeze)

It contails `.msi` for installing

#### Example project structure:

```
/package_name
        /some_packet
            /__init.py
            /module_name.py  # for an example contains valiable in code "module_1"
    /main.py
    /setup.py
    /some_module.py  # for an example contains valiable "module_2"
    /some_other_module.py  # for an example contains valiable "module_3"
```

#### Example of setup.py(simplified)

```
import cx_Freeze

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name="example",
    options={
        "build_exe": {
            "packages": ["asyncio"],
            "include_files": ["static\some_static_file.png"]
        },
        "bdist_msi": {
            "upgrade_code": "{492de237-1853-4599-a707-c283d567699f}"
        }
    },
    executables=[cx_Freeze.Executable("main.py")]
)
```

#### Current behavior

For creating `.msi` install file -> run command `python setup.py bdist_msi`. It will generate `.msi` files for installing application.
After installing this application: directory(where application is installed) will contain:

- `main.exe`
- `lib\some_packet` directory
- `lib\some_packet\module_name.pyc` file
- other files

**There are following statements:**

1) From root directory(where application is installed) i start search(via `grep -Rna` command under Ubuntu guest system, it's just more convenient for me) and valiable `module_1` could be found in directories(in `lib\some_packet\module_name.pyc`) and `module_2`/`module_3` couldn't be found.
 Details:

```
(v_decompile) any@any-pc:/mnt/hgfs/shar/example_installed$ grep -Rna "module_1" 
lib/some_packet/module_name.pyc:2:B�!]�@dZdS)module_1N)r�rr�PG:\heroes\installer-with-cx_Freeze\sources_of_project\some_packet\module_name.py<module>s 
(v_decompile) any@any-pc:/mnt/hgfs/shar/example_installed$ grep -Rna -a "module_2" 
(v_decompile) any@any-pc:/mnt/hgfs/shar/example_installed$ grep -Rna -a "module_3"
```

2) File `lib\some_packet\module_name.pyc` could be easily converted to original file(without comments) by e.g. [python-uncompyle6](https://github.com/rocky/python-uncompyle6).
Details:

```
(v_decompile) any@any-pc:/mnt/hgfs/shar/example_installed$ uncompyle6 lib/some_packet/module_name.pyc 
# uncompyle6 version 3.3.3 
# Python bytecode 3.6 (3379) 
# Decompiled from: Python 3.6.6 (default, Jul 20 2018, 15:39:05) 
# [GCC 4.8.4] 
# Embedded file name: G:\heroes\installer-with-cx_Freeze\sources_of_project\some_packet\module_name.py 
# Compiled at: 2019-07-07 11:28:50 
module_1 = 'module_1' 
# okay decompiling lib/some_packet/module_name.pyc
```

3) (solved with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56559453/how-to-fix-numpy-dependencies-path-on-a-python-3-7-3-script-on-linux-frozen-with/56592344#56592344)) In both points: file contains source path `G:\heroes\installer-with-cx_Freeze\sources_of_project\some_packet\module_name.py` It confuses me a bit. Application was installed from `.msi` and (as I understand) should not know about source directories (regarding path) which was used for creating last one.

#### Questions:

1. Is there any way to recover `some_module.py` and `some_other_module.py` to original files from `main.exe`?(like it could be done with `lib\some_packet\module_name.pyc`)
2. How to "hide" some other files in application into `main.exe` or somehow avoid converting `.pyc` to original files.(maybe some properties in `cx_Freeze`?)

#### Note:

It should be done with `cx_Freeze`.

PS: I don't want to create single `.exe`. I try to find convenient way for specifying which files should be stored in `main.exe` like it was done with `some_module.py` and `some_other_module.py`

PSS: At this moment I see only I way: put all files on `main.py` level :) But it will look weird for big project.

Comment: From the [documentation](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#single-file-executables), `cx_freeze` does not support building a single file exe.

Comment: @HenryYik yes, i've read that, but if I put all files on `main.py` level - it will be included in `.exe` :) Therefore I assume that there is some convenient way to do same for all files.

Comment: Your own words: "At this moment I see only I way: put all files on `main.py` level" reflect my opinion on your question as well.

Comment: @jpeg Yep, but there is one more interesting question -> #1, about recowering files. Maybe putting files for including them in `main.exe` doesn't have any sense, in case when it could be recovered from `.exe` :) Because main point of this question is "hiding" source code from end user.

Comment: Regarding your point 3) "Application [...] should not know about source directories (regarding path)": maybe the cx_Freeze option `replace_paths` described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56592344/8516269) can help you on this point?

Comment: @jpeg yeap :) it helps for #3

Comment: **Mod Note** Do not use voting fraud to place bounties. The votes will be reversed and you will not have the rep to apply the bounty.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting [How to obfuscate Python source code](https://smallsurething.com/how-to-obfuscate-python-source-code/):

> These two methods [using pyobfuscate and distributing bytecode] are really just a deterrent, not a secure way of hiding the code.
>
> If you want something a bit more robust, you should take a look at [Nuitka](http://www.nuitka.net/pages/overview.html), which compiles Python code to C++, so you can compile that and just distribute the executable. It seems to be broadly compatible with different libraries and different versions of Python.

See also [Python Code Obfuscation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/576963/8516269)

Comment: Will take a look as an option.

Comment: well, `nuitka` it looks inconvenient (especially point - you should keep 2 version of python and somehow friend them), I guess `nuitka` is another question. Anyway thanks for link.

Answer (score 0):

This [video](https://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=how+to+%e2%80%9chide%e2%80%9d+some+.py+files+into+.exe+with+cx_freeze%3f&docid=608051395366617230&mid=FAE11B289FB41008D232FAE11B289FB41008D232&view=detail&FORM=VIREHT) might help.
It talks about cxfreeze and how you can use cxfreeze to make a excutable, and I know it works for 3.4+ because the video uses python 3.4, but really your method should be fine...

Comment: Well, this video is just general for topic of "creating an executable file". It not very useful for my current question. But anyway thanks for this link, will be useful for beginners.

Comment: I do not really get your question.

Comment: Point is hide several source files during creation executalbe file. As I mentioned in `Note` section: I don't look how to craete single exetable files with all libraries, because it's not possible to be done with cx_Freeze.

Comment: under "hide" file I don't mean mark files as "hidden", I mean include source `.py` into `.exe` file. So second link is not about topic at all.